# Backend com banco de dados mysql e frontend em javascript(react-native)

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, react-native, back-end

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em javascript(para android)e gostaria de usar o mysql como banco de dados para essa aplicação, porem nao consegui usar o mysql no mesmo codigo entao fiz umas pesquisas que indicaram separar por backend e frontend só que desconheço a respeito. Se alguem tiver algum link explicando(pode ser em ingles/espanhol), ou me explicar como fazer esse backend (preferência em java) e como incluir esse codigo no js ficaria grato!

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo um aplicativo que poderá trocar informações com MySQL somente para confirmação de Cadastro!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pedro, acredito que o seu caso seja um pouco mais embaixo. Não sei o que pretende desenvolver, que tipo de serviço pretende, mas o ideal seria você separar as camadas sim, seguindo esse conceito:

- React/Javascript para o Front-end
- Serviço REST para entregar os dados
- Não embedar os dados no Aplicativo/Não usar database local

Database local é bom apenas para serviços de consulta rapida, tipo, Livro, aonde tem todos os capitulos escritos lá.

O serviço REST que sugiro, não importa muito a linguagem que você faça, Java, PHP, .NET, o que for, o importante é que essa camada converse com a Base de Dados, MySQL ou PostgreSQL ou sei lá e entregue os dados para sua aplicação, independente dela ser Android/iOS ou até mesmo um site, pois você atende todas as suas aplicações independente da plataforma.

Um artigo simples para criar uma API: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Exemplo de Uso:

- No React você cria um form de cadastro
- Envia por AJAX para a URL http://rest.seusite.com/api/v1/users/add
- O serviço adiciona o cadastro e retorna ok, ou false, depende né..
- Sua aplicação React responde cadastro realizado com sucesso e redireciona para a tela de lista de usuarios
- por sua vez essa tela de lista de usuarios requisita mais um ajax para http://rest.seusite.com/api/v1/users/list
- Aqui retorna um JSON com todos os usuarios cadastrados
- Sua aplicação React Lista os usuarios da sua aplicação REST
- E assim segue.....

Espero que tenha entendido o conceito e entenda que não há uma solução para o seu caso e sim várias. Abs

Comment: Obrigado, andei pesquisando hoje e está tudo de acordo com o que me respondeu. Eu só tinha achado soluções em php e estava tentando fugir pois não tenho experiência em php e realmente percebi que existem várias soluções! Valeu!